# Why is macOS Recovery in Japanese, when my language is set on english?

Tags: recovery, startup, language, utilities

My Macbook Pro(early 2015) functioned in english until I started up macOS Recovery to erase the startup disc with macOS Utilities.
It was originally bought used in Japan. 
I would like the entire system to function in english.